# Duplicidad de email de confirmacion cuando se dispara el callback desde el modelo User DEVISE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Acabo de terminar de seguir esta guia https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in el cual me funciono perfectamente, y active el modulo de confirmable para que cuando el admin aprobara la cuenta del usuario despues de su registro se le enviara un email de confirmacion despues de que el parametro del campo approved cambiara de false a true, pues esto lo logro mediante el siguiente callback dentro del modelo User:

```
after_update :user_approved_true

def user_approved_true
   if self.approved == true
      send_confirmation_instructions
   end
end
```

Pues funciona perfectamente, pero en lo que falla, es lo que hace doble, he buscado diferentes metodos, usado diferentes codigos, pero no logro conseguir que evite la duplicidad de email, alguien podria ayudarme, alguna solucion!

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
   end
end
```

PD: No he generado ningun controlador de Devise, todo lo condiciono desde el modelo User.

Aquí pueden ver más información sobre mi modelo:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


# Anula el email de confirmacion de usuario una vez este se registra

   after_create :skip_confirmation!

   def skip_confirmation!
     self.confirmed_at = Time.now.utc
   end


# Envia el email de confirmacion una vez el admin aprueba su cuenta [ EL PROBLEMA SE ORIGINA AQUI ]

   after_update :user_approved_true

   def user_approved_true
     if self.approved == true
       send_confirmation_instructions
     end
   end


# Verifica el estado de aprobacion de la cuenta

   def active_for_authentication?
     super && approved?
   end


# Activa el mensaje de alerta de no aprobado por el admin

   def inactive_message
     if !approved?
       :not_approved
     else
       super # Use whatever other message
     end
   end


# Condiciona el reseteo de contraseñas dependiendo el estado aprobacion de la cuenta

   def self.send_reset_password_instructions(attributes={})
     recoverable = find_or_initialize_with_errors(reset_password_keys, attributes, :not_found)
     if !recoverable.approved?
       recoverable.errors[:base] << I18n.t("devise.failure.not_approved")
     elsif recoverable.persisted?
       recoverable.send_reset_password_instructions
     end
     recoverable
   end


# Condiciona confirmar cuenta dependiendo el estado aprobacion de la cuenta

   def self.send_confirmation_instructions(attributes={})
     confirmable = find_or_initialize_with_errors(confirmation_keys, attributes, :not_found)
     if !confirmable.approved?
       confirmable.errors[:base] << I18n.t("devise.failure.not_approved")
     elsif confirmable.persisted?
       confirmable.send_confirmation_instructions
     end
     confirmable
   end

end
```

Comment: ¿podrías agregar el log completo de cuando el usuario es aprovado por el admin?

Comment: Que tal Alter Lagos! Aqui te dejo todo un evento de log, en el momento que dispara el callback:

https://gist.github.com/hernandezalek/0314a49a3d46dcea801175b137421c66

Comment: Efectivamente las líneas 6 y 7 muestran que el usuario ha sido aprobado 2 veces. ¿Esto significa que el método `user_approved_true` está siendo invocado 2 veces? ¿has probado a poner algún breakpoint o mensaje en la ejecución de ese método? ¿Que pasa si comentas `send_confirmation_instructions`? ¿envía solo un mensaje o ninguno? ¿Existe la posibilidad que el código que está aprobando al usuario esté ejecutandose 2 veces? ¿Puedes mostrar ése código?

Comment: Si comento send_confirmation_intrucctions, no pasa nada @AlterLagos solo actualiza el parametro y el email no se envia, no se si estaria bien que te comparta mi repositorio? Talvez puedas ver algo q yo no veo

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que cuando el usuario está aprobado este código se va a ejecutar cada vez que se actualice el usuario:

```
   after_update :user_approved_true

   def user_approved_true
     if self.approved == true
       send_confirmation_instructions
     end
   end
```

Eso implica que si se cambia el nombre o la contraseña, por ejemplo, y el usuario está aprobado, también enviará la confirmación. Podrías probar con:

```
   def user_approved_true
     send_confirmation_instructions if approved_changed? && approved
   end
```

Así solo llamará al método de confirmación cuando el valor de `approved` haya pasado de `false` a `true`.

Comment: Hola Alter, probe tu codigo y aunque si no me habia percatado de que tenia que validar eso, continua enviando el doble email por alguna razon, en realidad no deberia, pero a veces siento como que si de alguna forma junto a mi callback hay algo mas en devise q se activa y hace q tambien devise lo envie, pero no hallo manera de condicionar eso